# ng-checked in a radio button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

In my angular application, I am looping through a collection and displaying the records with `input type="radio"`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in vm.pagedAccounts.items"
                ng-class="{ 'highlight': (account.rowIsSelected) }"
                <td>
                    <input
                        ng-model="account.rowIsSelected"
                        value="{{account}}"
                        name="selectedAccount"
                        ng-checked="account.rowIsSelected"
                        ng-change="vm.selectAccount(account)"
                        type="radio">
                </td>
```

In my controller, I first set `rowIsSelected` property to false for all the accounts.

```
response.data.results.forEach(function(account) {
   account.rowIsSelected = false;
});
```

So, I just make sure whenever `account.rowIsSelected` is set to something, make that checked.

This is working fine.

But, in the `selectAccount` function, if a different account is clicked, I want to `remove the previous all highlights and highlight the current one`.

```
    vm.selectAccount = function (account) {
        if (account.rowIsSelected) {

            //First set all false
            vm.pagedAccounts.items.forEach(function(account) {
                account.rowIsSelected = false;
            });

            var selectedAccount = vm.pagedAccounts.items
                .filter(function(x){
                    return x.id=== account.id;
                });

            //Then set only that accounts property to true
            selectedAccount[0].rowIsSelected = true;
        }
```

But if I click the same row twice, `it is no longer checked. I want to keep it checked and highlighted`.

**How to do it?
Does whatever I am doing seem right?
Please help.**

Comment: Do not use ng-checked and ng-model on same element. I think you should always use ng-model.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Then how can I make the radio button checked on selecting it ?

Comment: Angular is funky when it comes to radio button. You should be using `ngModel` and not `ngChecked` for those.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
vm.selectAccount = function (checkedItem) {
    var selectedAccount;
    vm.pagedAccounts.items.forEach(function(account) {
        if(checkedItem.id == account.id){
           selectedAccount = account;
           account.rowIsSelected = true;
        }else{
           account.rowIsSelected = false;
        }

    });
    //Then set only that accounts property to true
    selectedAccount[0].rowIsSelected = true;
```

}

Comment: If I click the same row twice, checked being removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should organize your radio buttons in a bit different way, like it recommends [angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in vm.pagedAccounts.items"
    ng-class="{ 'highlight': vm.pagedAccounts.selected === account }">
    <td>
        <input
            ng-model="vm.pagedAccounts.selected"
            ng-value="account"
            type="radio">
     </td>
...
```

And radio buttons should be automatically selected, when `ng-model` values is equal to `ng-value`, so you don't need any specific logic or `ng-checked`, etc.

Comment: Should not it be `ng-value="{{account}}"? Also, the row is being highlighted, but the radio button seems not to be checked.

Comment: `ng-value="{{account}}` you don't need parentheses, since there we use `ng-` directive. Also you can avoid `ng-chage`, like in example. I updated the draft, try this one.